# How to prevent storing some random keys in rails redis store?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.2, redis

I am using redis-store for caching in my rails application.When i look at my keys which stored in the redis-store using command redis-cli -> KEYS *.It shows some random keys.

```
62100f3ca06a136907ac421f33e904cbc1f6b38c"
20) "user_id:27"
21) "1102a994ff6e1a83ae4384d1ea6c5bea092f8f44"
22) "03518bcbf9a2ccc36b67784088e3ce7511fef4ba"
23) "user_id:32"
24) "views/footer"
25) "http://localhost:3000/assets/bg-sitenavon.jpg?"
26) "ed_id"
```

When i get the values of the random keys,It shows the javascript codes which i used in my application.

Any idea?

Comment: Sounds like caches of asset intermediaries.

Comment: Should i prevent it or should i not ?

Comment: I wouldn't, although you can set config.assets.cache_store if you want that cached separately from everything else